# How to pass struct with string data in PINVOKE?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I'm stuck by passing struct with string data from C# code to C++ dll.

c++ code

```
typedef struct 
{
    LPCSTR lpLibFileName;
    LPCSTR lpProcName;
    LPVOID pPointer1;
    LPVOID pPointer2;
} ENTITY, *PENTITY, *LPENTITY;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Test(LPENTITY entryList, int size);

int Test(LPENTITY entryList, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ENTITY e = entryList[i];
        // the char* value doesn't get passed correctly.
        cout << e.lpLibFileName << e.lpProcName << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

c# code

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private class Entity
{
    public string lpLibFileName;
    public string lpProcName;
    public IntPtr pPointer1;
    public IntPtr pPointer2;
}

[DllImport("cpp.dll")]
private static extern int Test(
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]Entity[] entities,
    int size);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var entries = new[]
        {
            new Entity
                {
                    lpLibFileName = "comdlg32",
                    lpProcName = "PrintDlgExW",
                    pPointer1 = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new PrintDlgEx(PrintDlgExCallback)),
                    pPointer2 = IntPtr.Zero,
                },
            new Entity
                {
                    lpLibFileName = "shell32",
                    lpProcName = "ShellAboutW",
                    pPointer1 = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new ShellAbout(ShellAboutCallback)),
                    pPointer2 = IntPtr.Zero,
                },
        };
    var ret = Test(entries, entries.Length);
}
```

The PINVOKE was triggered, but the char* data like lpLibFileName and lpProcName cannot be passed correctly. Did I miss something? How to correct it?

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing the required CallingConvention property in your [DllImport] attribute.  The default is Stdcall but your function is Cdecl.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have used stdcall instead of cdecl in c++ code. But what actually blocked me is that I defined my structure as 'class' in c# code instead of 'struct'. After changing it back to struct, everything worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code maps a C# class onto a native struct. Because a C# class is a reference type then it will be marshalled as a reference. So your code passes an array of references that gets marshalled to an array of pointers on the native side.

But the native code expects a pointer to an array of structs which are value types. So the simplest solution is to change the declaration of `Entity` to be a `struct` rather than a `class`.

The other issues that I can see:

1. The native code appears to be using the `cdecl` calling convention. You'll need to change the C# code to match.
2. You are decorating the array parameter with `Out`. You cannot marshal modifications to the `string` fields back to the managed code.
3. You will need to make sure that you keep alive the delegates that you pass to  `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` to stop them being collected.

Answer (score 0):

When passing parameter like array of custom structures, use 'struct' instead of 'class' when defining your own data structure.  After I changing it back to struct, everything worked fine.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private struct Entity
{
    public string lpLibFileName;
    public string lpProcName;
    public IntPtr pPointer1;
    public IntPtr pPointer2;
}
```